# Cannot convert from double to decimal error

Tags: c#

For this assignment I need to do some stuff with a BankAccount program, but first I need to copy the get the example running. I've copied the code from the assignment sheet exactly as shown in the screenshots below, but I'm getting the errors shown below.

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'decimal' Line 13 Column 51
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'BankAccount.BankAccount.BankAccount(decimal)' has some invalid arguments Line 13 Column 35    
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'decimal' Line 13 Column 30 
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'BankAccount.BankAccount.Withdraw(decimal)' has some invalid arguments Line 18 Column 13
```

I have no idea what's causing these errors as I don't think I've used a double once, and a very quick Google of the errors didn't help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BankAccount
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Bank Account & Print Balance
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount(142.50);
            Console.WriteLine("Account Balance is: " + account.ToString());

            // Withdraw £30.25
            Console.WriteLine("Withdrawing £30.25");
            account.Withdraw(30.25);

            // Print balance again
            Console.WriteLine("Account Balance is: " + account.ToString());
        }
    }
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BankAccount
{
   public class BankAccount
    {
       private decimal _balance;

       public decimal Balance
       {
           get { return _balance; }
           private set { _balance = value; }
       }

       //Constructor: Constructs a new Bank Account with 0 balance
       public BankAccount()
       {
           Balance = 0;
       }

       //Constructor: Constructs a new Bank Account with the specified balance
       public BankAccount(decimal balance)
       {
           Balance = balance;
       }

       //Deposits the specified amount into the Bank Account
       public void Deposit(decimal amount)
       {
           Balance += amount;
       }

       //Withdraws the specified amount from the Bank Account
       public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
       {
           Balance -= amount;
       }

       //ToString Override
       public override string ToString()
       {
           return string.Format("{0}: Balance = {1}", "BankAccount", Balance);

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the body of your question instead of as a picture. Also tell us where the errors are occurring in the code so we don't have to try to figure out where things are happening.

Comment: Decimal literals are denoted with an `m` suffix so you need to use `new BankAccount(142.50m)` if the constructor requires a `decimal` argument.

Comment: I would bet you have a function which returns a double which you are trying to pass to a decimal with no cast.  That said, I can't see your code since my work blocks imgur.

Comment: I can't see the screenshot but the errors seem pretty clear.  You're interchangably using `decimal` and `double`.  You either need to change data types or cast.  Hint: for financial apps `decimal` is better to use than `double` since it can represent base-10 fractions exactly while `double` cannot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here:

```
 BankAccount account = new BankAccount(142.50);
```

you are passing the `double` literal `142.50`. BankAccount, however, expects a [`decimal` literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead:

```
 BankAccount account = new BankAccount(142.50m);
```

Note the `m` behind the number.

Comment: Awesome, that's it sorted. I'll mark your answer as right when StackOverflow allows me to in 10 minutes. 

Not sure why the assignment sheet contains this error, I guess they'd have pointed it out in the lab session that there was an error once somebody realised, but unfortunately I slept through it...

Comment: Note that you need to add the m when you call the `Withdraw` method as well or anywhere else a decimal is used.

Answer (score 6):

There is simple answer (and even example) in [MSDN for C#'s `decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

You've right to use `decimal` for this kind of operation:

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

And using `decimal` literals requires `m` suffix:

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M, for example:
>
> `decimal myMoney = 300.5m;`
>
> **Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double and generates a compiler error.**

Also two more import points from docs:

> - There is no implicit conversion between floating-point types and the decimal type; therefore, a cast must be used to convert between these two types.
> - You can also mix decimal and numeric integral types in the same expression. However, mixing decimal and floating-point types without a cast causes a compilation error.

This is important so you won't slowly build up error for example by summing up many [`0.1` which is periodic number in binary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.1%20to%20binary).